# Dealing with tuples of different types in json in Swift

Tags: json, swift, date, tuples

I want to save an array of tuples where one element is the value and the other element is the Date in Swift 3.

Here is some hard coded example.

```
var currentDateTime = NSDate()

var confArray: [(conf: Int, date: NSDate)] = []

confArray.append((4, currentDateTime.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * -15)))
confArray.append((3, currentDateTime.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * -7)))
confArray.append((3, currentDateTime))
confArray.append((1, currentDateTime.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 1)))
confArray.append((5, currentDateTime.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 2)))
confArray.append((3, currentDateTime.addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 24 * 3)))
```

However, it seems that JSON doesn't allow for tuples, and throws an error when I do something like this.

```
let trackingContent = ["key": confArray ]
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: trackingContent, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
```

Is there a way around this?

I've thought about converting both elements into String and saving them as an array of Strings instead. However, converting Date to String requires multiple lines, and I would have to convert it back.
Please let me know if there is a more efficient way to store tuples in JSON or if I'm missing something. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to use array type? My suggestion is converting `confArray` to `[Int: [NSDate]]`

Comment: You can also use the timestamps (timeIntervalSince1970) instead of NSDate. It can be easily converted back to Date

Comment: @DaoNguyen the int values aren't unique so it would have to be `[NSDate: Int]`  or `[[Int: NSDate]]`. Would it be possible to get the date without knowing the value in the second case? I need the confArray to be ordered so I can access the date in the 3rd element, value in 5th, etc.

Comment: @Woof Thanks! Using timeIntervalSince1970 makes sense. I was thinking about using Date instead of NSDate, but NSDate seems better if I have to switch between String and NSDate.

Comment: @DaoNguyen you can't use an Int as the dictionary keys when using JSON it needs to be string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's play-ground!

```
import Foundation

typealias Conf = (idx: Int, interval: TimeInterval)
typealias JSConf = [String]

extension Array where Element == Conf {
    func encode() -> JSConf {
        return map { "\($0.idx):\($0.interval)" }
    }

    static func decode(_ jsConf: JSConf) -> [Conf] {
        return jsConf.map({ e -> Conf in
            let comps = e.components(separatedBy: ":")
            return (Int(comps.first!)!, Double(comps.last!)!)
        })
    }
}

var confs: [Conf] = []
confs.append((4, 60 * 60 * 24 * -15))
confs.append((3, 60 * 60 * 24 * -7))
confs.append((3, 0))
confs.append((1, 60 * 60 * 24 * 1))
confs.append((5, 60 * 60 * 24 * 2))
confs.append((3, 60 * 60 * 24 * 3))

let encode = confs.encode()

let data = ["key": encode]
do {
    let _ = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

let decode = [Conf].decode(encode)

print(decode)
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Wow thanks! I'll just switch time interval to timeIntervalSince1970 instead of time from now, and I think it's exactly what I was looking for!